# What is the easiest way to prove by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, definition, proof-explanation

Is there any easy way to do this? I get the basic step.. where you prove it for some number.. but I don't get the induction step.

Do you literally take the given equation that you just proved with the basic step.. and plug in (k+1)?

I really don't understand how to prove by induction other than the general explanation where you show that if it works for some number, than it will also work for some number + 1 based on assumptions.

Thanks

Comment: You plug in for k+1 and then you check if you can manipulate the formula to look just like the formula for k, except it has k+1 instead of k. You have now proven that if the formula looks a certain way for k, then it doesn't change for the integer that comes after k. Try out your formula for k with the basic step, see where it leads you.

Comment: To perform this inductive step, formally name your predicate P and assume $P(n)$ is true, then pass in $n+1$ as $P(n+1)$. By re-factoring the equation algebraically you will be able to determine if the function naturally incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of Induction says that $\forall P[[P(0) \wedge \forall k\in \mathbb{N}(P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)]\Rightarrow \forall b\in \mathbb{N} [P(n)]]$...thus if $P$ is any predictate and you prove $P$ for $n=0$ $and$ then assuming that it is true for $n=k$ you prove $P$ for $n=k+1$ then $P$ is true forall $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So, in general when you assume $P(n)$, then you put the value of $n$ in $P$ and for $n+1$ you replace it by $n+1$ and after some manipulation you need to decompose it in $P(n)$ and some other terms so that you can use your induction hypothesis. Most of the time this thing works, but every problem has different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

First we show that it holds for the "base case", usually $n=1$ or $n=0$ but that can vary.

Then we assume it holds for $n=k$ and then prove that *provided* it holds for $n=k$ it will also hold for $k+1$. In other words, if the formula is valid for an integer, it will always be valid for the next integer.

Combining this with our original demonstration that it is true for $n=1$, it means it will be true for $n=2$. But if it is true for $n=2$ it should be true for the next integer, i.e, $n=3$. This is kind of like a "domino effect" that ad infinitum.